# Why iptables not working with string match using x-forwarded-for?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, networking, cloudflare, iptables

I have a webserver running running with Apache on Ubuntu behind Cloudflare. I want to block a user using the iptables of the webserver. Here I want to implement to string match feature of iptables and drop the connection. Here is my rule which does not work:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m string --string "x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
```

After adding this rule the client is still able to hit the server.

I know Cloudflare's specific header for client IP that is **cf-connecting-ip**. I am able to block the client with this. Here is the rule which works fine:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m string --string "cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
```

The traffic from Cloudflare to the Web server is HTTP (port 80).

I have a load-balancer (haproxy) and some of the domains are running through this instead of Cloudflare. That is why I want to use XFF because **cf-connecting-ip** is specific to Cloudflare and XFF is supported by both.

I can see Cloudflare is properly attaching both **cf-connecting-ip** and XFF headers. Here is the output of tcpdump among multiple requests:

```
tcpdump -A -s 65535 'tcp port 80' | grep 216.244.66.205
```

> ```
> x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205
> cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205
> x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205
> cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205
> x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205
> cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205
> x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205
> cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205
> ```

Somehow the iptables are able to detect the string **cf-connecting-ip** but not **x-forwarded-for**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers are at the Application Layer, while IPTables works lower down in the TCP/IP stack. The data you are looking to filter based on is not visible to IPTables.

For websites behind Cloudflare you should configure IPTables to only allow Cloudflare IP addresses through, and use the Cloudflare Firewall to block the client IP addresses.

Comment: As my webserver only serving http (80) (not https), every bit of the data is visible to Iptables. You should have had an idea looking at the question when i said it is working fine with **cf-connecting-ip** and the output of tcpdump command. For your other suggestions i would say you did not read the entire question or this is my bad i could not make it more simple. I can block bad IPs at Cloudflare but I also have a haproxy LB and I don't want to manage the rules at two places. Also adding these iptables rules is automated by some bad users+bots detection scripts which monitor logs.

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question, hope it can help someone.

The issue was due to the Case of the letters (Upper+Lower).

So, I just added an extra option to iptables rule that is `--icase` which ignores the case (case-insensitive match).

Now the command is as follows and it is working for both: cloudflare and my own haproxy based load-balancer:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m string --string "x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205" --algo bm --to 65535 --icase -j DROP
```